# SQL where condition using IF

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table LEVEL like this

```
|name|level|type||
|a   | 1   | a1  |
|b   | 1   | a2  |
|c   | 2   | a1  |
|d   | 1   | a1  |
|e   | 3   | a3  |
|a   | 1   | a1  |
|a   | 1   | a1  |
```

I need a stored procedure to get based on rule

```
if I send @name = a and @level = 1
- select all from table level where name = @name
if I send @name = b and @level = 2
- select all from table level where type = @type
if I send @name = b and @level = 3
- select all from table level where type = @type
```

I create procedure like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM LEVEL
WHERE
((@LEVEL IS NULL) OR 
(RIGHT(LEVEL,1) = RIGHT(@LEVEL,1) AND RIGHT(@LEVEL,1) = '1' AND NAME = @NAME) OR
(RIGHT(LEVEL,1) = RIGHT(@LEVEL,1) AND RIGHT(@LEVEL,1) = '2' AND TYPE = @TYPE) OR
(RIGHT(LEVEL,1) = RIGHT(@LEVEL,1) AND RIGHT(@LEVEL,1) = '3' AND TYPE = @TYPE))
```

But when I send `@level = 1, @name = a, and @type = a1`, still return all.

I think my WHERE clause is wrong, but no idea where and why?

Comment: a `query` or a `stored-procedure`?

Comment: Why you are given Right? see my answer will help you or not.

Comment: because from the old data level is not always 1 but 01 :), this will become stored procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this.  There is data mismatch for the condition, so I changed the parameter value.

```
Declare @table table (name varchar(5), level int, type varchar(5))

insert into @table values ('a', 1,'a1'),('b', 1,'a2'),('c', 2,'a1'),('d', 1,'a1'),('e', 3,'a3'),('a', 1,'a1'),('a', 1,'a1')

--uncomment for other parameter value
--declare @name varchar(5) = 'a', @level int = 1, @type varchar(5) = 'a1'
declare @name varchar(5) = 'b', @level int = 1, @type varchar(5) = 'a2' -- There is no rows, for @name = 'b' and @level (2, 3) and @type = 'a1'

select * from @table where  
(   name = @name and level = @level and 
    ( 
        (@name = 'a' and @level = 1 )
        or
    ( 
        (@name = 'b' and ( @level in (1, 2 ,3) )) and type = @type ) -- show only row 1 
    )
)
```

Output will be from first comment parameter list

```
name    level   type
a        1       a1
a        1       a1
a        1       a1
```

Output will be from second uncomment parameter list

```
name    level   type
b        1       a2
```

Comment: there is no gap between @ and parameter name. just remove and try will give the result. Also why you used RIGHT function when a single valuein the column

Answer (score 0):

Use `union all`;

```
select *
from level
where name = @name and 
@level = 1 and @name = 'a'
--above select query return any result if  @name = a and @level = 1

union all

select *
from level
where type = @type and 
@name = 'b' and @level in (2, 3)
--above select query return any result 
--if @name = b and @level = 2 or @name = b and @level = 3
```

Comment: so I need to select * from (that's union all) and filter it with level? sorry if confusing

Comment: Entire `select` query is valid for all the three case. If the proper condition matched then only the each `select` query return results

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from level
Where 
(Name='a' and @level = 1)
Or
(Type=@type and @level=2 and @name='b')
Or
(Type=@type and @level=3 and @name='b')
```